# Перегрузка операторов C++. Умножение на константу

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Доброго времени суток!

Я создал структуру, которая имеет следующий вид:

```
struct variables {
    double x,y,z;
    double u,v,w;
    vector <double> J;
    vector <double> Omega;
    variables();
};
```

которую мне бы хотелось уметь умножать на число типа double, т.е. каждый элемент структуры умножить на это самое число (в том числе элементы массивов).

На данный момент я реализовал это с помощью функции внутри структуры, но мне хотелось бы сделать это с помощью переопределения оператора умножения.

Собственно, вопрос заключается в том, как это нужно сделать? Нужно ли для этого отдельно реализовывать два оператора внутри структуры типа

```
friend const variables operator*(const variables& left, const double& right);
friend const variables operator*(const double& left, const variables& right);
```

или можно сделать это как-то иначе?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, если вы хотите иметь возможность умножать на скаляр типа `double` и справа, и слева, то для этого придется реализовать две версии перегруженного оператора `operator *`: один с параметром `double` слева, другой - один с параметром `double` справа. (В данном случае нет необходимости передавать параметры типа `double` по константный ссылке. Логичнее передавать просто по значению.)

Второй оператор (с параметром `double` справа) может быть перегружен как функцией-членом, так и отдельной функцией. Первый (с параметром `double` слева) может быть реализован *только* отдельной функцией. По этой причине, для единообразия, обе версии оператора обычно перегружают отдельной функцией, хотя такого единообразия формально не требуется.

Эти отдельные функции не обязаны быть friend-функциями. Но если вы в них хотите работать напрямую с закрытыми внутренностями класса (а обычно это нужно), то придется их объявить как friend-функции.

И, наконец, вас никто не заставляет *реализовывать* эти функции прямо внутри класса. Внутри класса должны располагаться только friend-объявления этих функций, а их реализацию (определения) вы можете расположить снаружи.

Однако у вас в в данный момент ваш класс объявлен как `struct` и все его внутренности полностью доступны внешнему миру. В такой ситуации вам вообще не нужны friend-функции и объявлять ваши операторы внутри класса как friend-функции никакой необходимости нет.

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы реализуете friend-функцию (оператор), вы на самом деле реализуете внешнюю функцию, просто она имеет доступ к приватным полям. Для простых структур в этом нет смысла, т.к. все поля публичны, можно реализовать просто внешнюю функцию (оператор).

К сожалению, реализовывать придется либо оба оператора: правый и левый, либо использовать библиотечные генераторы наподобие  boost::operators [(пример)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#example). Но от них может пострадать производительность для некоторых случаев. В предложениях к стандарту есть автоматическая генерация операторов, но я не знаю, какой статус оно сейчас имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно просто внутри структуры перегрузить оператор

```
const variables operator*(variables& i) {
    x * i.x;
//    etc
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к задаче умножения на скаляр типа `double`?